# Chrome extension jump to URL

Tags: url, google-chrome

I would like to make a google chrome extension. I want to add a function, so when i click on it's icon, it will open a new tab with a specific URL. How can I do that?
Sorry for bad english, I'm just learning that language ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a link in a new tab when you click on a page action icon you can use the onClicked method of the pageAction: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked

So, in the background page or script add the following lines:

```
    chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        windowObjectReference = window.open("http://google.com/", "DescriptiveWindowName", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");  
});
```

Note, that onClicked event is NOT fired when page action has a popup page that is displayed when page action is clicked. So in order to use onCLicked event you should NOT have a page action popup page